# Fetching large volume of data with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, mybatis

I've been trying to fetch data using SpringBoot for my REST API, and the request I'm making keeps timing out when I try to fetch the data I need. The expected results from the fetch request will return ~50 columns and around 20k records. I tried limiting my query to 3k records and my fetch request got through, but I really need to get all the records in one go. I have all the data I need staged in a Materialized View, so there should not be any problem with the query, and running a quick select * in SQL plus will take around 10 sec to return all the records. Any ideas on how I get through this without getting timed out?

EDIT: Testing the API through Insomnia, I am not getting any errors, but just get a "No body returned for response" message after 5 minutes.

Some codes below:

**DataListController.java**

```
@ApiResponses(value = {
    @ApiResponse(code = 401, message = "Unauthenticated session for current user"),
    @ApiResponse(code = 403, message = "Insufficient privileges for current user"),
    @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Unhandled system exception")
})
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public class DataListController {

    private DataSource dataSource;
    DataListService dataListService;

    @Autowired
    public DataListController(
            DataListService dataListService,
            DataSource dataSource
    ) {
        this.dataListService = dataListService;
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

@ApiOperation(
            value = "Fetch All Data"
    )
    @ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, response = DataListRecord.class, responseContainer = "List", message = "Fetch all records")
    })
    @GetMapping({"/data/list"})
    public HttpEntity<List<Map>> getAllData(HttpServletResponse response) {
        List<Map> result = dataListService.getAllData();
        return ResponseEntity.ok(result);
    }
}
```

**DataListService.java**

```
@Service
public class DataListService {

    private DataListDao dataListDao;

    @Autowired
    public DataListService(
            DataListDao dataListDao
    ) {
        this.dataListDao = dataListDao;
    }

    public List<Map> getAllData() {
        return dataListDao.getAllData();
    }
}
```

**DataListDao.java**

```
@Mapper
public interface DataListDao {

    public List<Map> getAllData();

}
```

**DataListDao.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper
        PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN"
        "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">

<mapper namespace="project.repository.DataListDao">

    <select id="getAllData" resultType="map">
        select * from MV_DATA_LIST
    </select>

</mapper>
```

Comment: What exactly times out? The client calling the rest controller? Or the call from the rest controller to the database?

Comment: The second one, rest controller to DB

Comment: Can you please share your mybatis configuration and a stacktrace of the error?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the timeout of your embedded Tomcat

Add this setting to your application.properties

```
server.connection-timeout=1200000
```

Or in the case, you are using properties.yml

```
server:
  connection-timeout: 1200000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can increase `defaultStatementTimeout` in your mybatis configuration to prevent calls to the database to time out. According to the [documentation](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html) the default value is 25s.